# Is dhclient.conf used during boot when bringing up network interfaces?

Tags: networking, boot, startup, dhcp

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 32bit Server on a single-board computer.  I want the option of using the Ethernet interface (`eth0`) as a backend to control the computer if it's connected.  I'm also lazy: if the cable is plugged in and I power the computer, I want eth0 up and running; in the event no cable is plugged in to eth0 upon powerup, I would like to be able to significantly reduce time it takes to bring `eth0` `up' during boot.

I had thought that simply changing the DHCP `timeout` value to something small would do the job, but even after editing the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, I still get the same long boot times when the cable is unplugged.

I understand the value of a robust bootup sequence for servers (see top answer for [1]), but I don't understand why changes to `dhclient.conf` are ignored during boot.  Is there anything else going on under the hood that I'm not aware of?  Perhaps I'm approaching the problem the wrong way (in which case I might need to ask a different question!)?

Thanks in advance for any input.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
...
```

My `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file has uncommented and changed the line:

```
timeout 5;
```

[1] ["Waiting for network configuration" adding 3 to 5 minutes to boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63456/waiting-for-network-configuration-adding-3-to-5-minutes-to-boot-time?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `auto` instead of `allow-hotplug`?  If you use `allow-hotplug` and your hardware supports link detection, then your system will not even try doing DHCP if there is no link detected.

Another value you may want to look at changing is in the `/etc/default/ifupdown` file.  Consider setting the `IFUPDOWN_TIMEOUT` timeout.

Comment: I did consider using allow-hotplug, but eth0 does not come up automatically when the cable is plugged in.  

It is unclear if plugging/unplugging an Ethernet cable is considered a hotplug event (as opposed to adding/removing a wireless USB dongle, which is).  My reference, which might be a tad dated, is: 
http://lists.debian.org/debian-doc/2008/02/msg00010.html

Comment: I am trying your /e/d/ifupdown suggestion, but the file wasn't initially present and I can't find documentation mentioning the file or the variable IFUPDOWN_TIMEOUT.  Creating /e/d/ifupdown and adding 'IFUPDOWN_TIMEOUT = 5' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried `allow-hotplug` again, this time with `ifplugd`, and it works.  When `eth0` is configured as `allow-hotplug`, it is not started by `/e/init.d/networking`, avoiding the DHCP timeout issues.  `ifplugd` will then configure `eth0` at boot if a cable is plugged in.

So, I've got a method to accomplish what I want, but the original question still irks me, is `dhclient.conf` being ignored during boot?