# Disable network configuration services during boot time

Tags: networking

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 after booting it taking more time for network configuration.this happen before login.
how to disable this services, could you please help us.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/63456/12864)?

Answer (score 12):

A better ideea than disabling the service is to remove the sleep time. To do this, open `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` with your favourite editor, and around line 25 you should see the following lines of code:

```
# Plymouth errors should not stop the script because we *must* reach
# the end of this script to avoid letting the system spin forever
# waiting on it to start.
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting for network configuration…” || :
sleep 40
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration…” || :
sleep 59
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Booting system without full network configuration…” || :
```

To solve your problem, just comment the sleep times (add '#' in front of the text). It should look like this:

```
# Plymouth errors should not stop the script because we *must* reach
# the end of this script to avoid letting the system spin forever
# waiting on it to start.
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting for network configuration…” || :
#sleep 40
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration…” || :
#sleep 59
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Booting system without full network configuration…” || :
```

Answer (score 5):

In `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`

replace:

```
start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot
```

with:

```
start on (filesystem) or failsafe-boot
```