# Can't boot - "Waiting for Network Configuration"

Tags: boot, networking, 13.10

After an update on 13.10, my PC won't boot Ubuntu any longer.

It displays the infamous "Waiting for Network Configuration" message and then hangs.

I can go into recovery mode, and choose "Start networking" and then go to a root prompt, and that works fine. Ping works. /etc/network/interfaces contains just the two lines "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback".

I've double-checked that my network is working, the cable is working (it works on another PC) and the network card seems to indicate a connection.

Any suggestions on how to get my PC booted again? Right now I'm limited to a root shell prompt.

Comment: I've tried deleting everything in /var/run/dbus; there were two files left there. Rebooted, same issue. I tried removing the 120 second wait in /etc/init/failsafe.conf. Same result. At this stage my workstation is effectively dead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have already checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/63456/waiting-for-network-configuration-adding-3-to-5-minutes-to-boot-time?rq=1?

Comment: Yes, I checked every issue I could find on this topic. It's something else... I'll try an older kernel tomorrow.

Comment: I tried reverting to an older kernel, and emptying /etc/network/interfaces completely, changes nothing. There's a 2-minute wait "Waiting for network configuration..." and then it says, "Booting system without full network configuration" and that's it - doesn't boot.

Comment: I've reinstalled Ubuntu, there seems no other fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do something like this?

In `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` replace:

```
start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot
```

with:

```
start on (filesystem) or failsafe-boot
```

From [Disable network configuration services during boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185515/disable-network-configuration-services-during-boot-time)