# Why does booting fail when /etc/network/interfaces file is misconfigured

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager, interface

I often edit /etc/network/interfaces file to setup ad-hoc connection among PCs. If I happen to reboot the system, the system waits for a long time saying 'Waiting for Network Configuration...'.

Recently I emptied the file as such and the system didn't boot (or complain) at all. I had to go through a Live-USB system and had to fill it for it to work.

1. How is this 'networking' aspect made a 'compulsory' for booting? Can this dependency be overridden?

Comment: There might be some service depending on networking to start. And you should always have at least a localhost entry in `interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

You need these two lines in your /etc/network/interfaces file **always**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

There are system critical programs that need this local network information to operate.

See the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63456/waiting-for-network-configuration-adding-3-to-5-minutes-to-boot-time) that explains a bit more about it.

Comment: "...  this is a new behavior, documented in the 11.10 release notes, that I actually developed together with Scott Moser as an effort to make server boot more reliable." OK!

But what is this so essential "local" network capability?